# Powershell copy-item, store new folder as variable

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a simple script to move a directory to a secured location on our servers. I want to pull the new file location as a variable to include in an email that I have labeled $secure. Any help would be appreciated - Thanks!

```
Write-Host "Enter Package Location: " -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Green
$package = Read-Host
Copy-Item -Path $package -Destination "C:\PS" -Force -Recurse
$secure = ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-PassThru` parameter with `Copy-Item`:

```
$secure = Copy-Item -Path $package -Destination "C:\PS" -Force -Recurse -PassThru
```

to get the copied item(s)

---

To just get the new root directory (ie. "C:\PS\packagedir"), use `Split-Path -Leaf` to grab the folder name from `$package` and combine with the destination path using `Join-Path`:

```
Write-Host "Enter Package Location: " -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Green
$package = Read-Host
$destination = "C:\PS"
Copy-Item -Path $package -Destination $destination -Force -Recurse
$secure = Get-Item (Join-Path $destination -ChildPath (Split-Path $package -Leaf))
```

Comment: Thanks! Ideally I would like just the folder structure as the variable, not the contents in these directories though, is there a way to get only that?

Comment: @RyanTice you bet! Updated the answer